# How does this JS work out odd or even

Tags: javascript, boolean, arrow-functions

Whilst reading Javascript Allonge I got stuck trying to figure out why this;

```
((n) => {
  const even = (x) => {
    if (x === 0)
      return true;
    else
      return !even(x - 1);
  }
  return even(n)
})(97)
```

returns true of false depending on the number supplied being odd or even.

When I look at it I think it is checking if the number supplied is 0 and if not subtracting 1 then checking again. This would mean the number eventually reached 0 and returns true. This is obviously NOT what is happening as for 97 it returns false and 96 true.

The only thing I don't know here is the bang before even in `return !even(x -1);`.

Comment: Totally unnecessary use of const and arrow functions -- I don't trust this guide you're reading! o.O

Comment: At this point he is just making a point about functions. You are right about the extra const and funcs in there!

Comment: Also, I think you are close as to how this is working. I believe it is `not`ing the return value n number of times as it unrolls the recursive function call stack. So, for odd numbers, it will be an odd number of `!true` which will result in false, and for even numbers it will result in an even number of `!true`, which is true. i.e. `!!!!!true === false`, and `!!true === true`. Why anyone in their right mind would do this, on the other hand, I am not sure.. lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, this is terrible, in a wonderful kind of way. What a way to write code to check for odd and even numbers!

The first thing to note is that this is a recursive function: it calls itself repeatedly. Each time, it decrements the number concerned, so it eventually gets all the way down to `0`.

The "clever" thing that this code does is the `!`, which inverts the boolean result of the function call. `true` becomes `false` and `false` becomes true. You can do this repeatedly: `!!true` is `true` and `!!!true` is `false`.

Essentially, this code can be reduced to something like the following:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!true;
```

If there are an even number of `!` negations, we end up with `true`. If there are an odd number, we end up with `false`.

The code you cite adds *n* `!` logical NOT operators to `true`, where *n* is the value that we're testing. An odd number of `!`s results in `false`; an even number results in `true`.

This is clever code: it is not good code to use in production! [It's somewhere in the region of 1200 times slower than the simple `% 2` test.](https://esbench.com/bench/5893bcff99634800a0347744)

Comment: Hahaha(for the !!!!!!!!s). Thank you! I can go to sleep now:) Makes perfect sense. This snippet is just an example he is using to explain funcs and closure and evaluating expressions. So it is exaggerated on purpose.

Comment: I'm upvoting this since you actually using 97 exclamation points in your example (and it's accurate).

Comment: @RionWilliams I'd like to point out that I used Javascript to make the 97 exclamation points! So meta.

Comment: @lonesomeday Here is the chapter with this code in. https://leanpub.com/javascriptallongesix/read#closures He is demonstrating writing functions so I am sure he would not write like this otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially stringing together N `!` operations, where N is the the input number. For example, if N is 3, then `!!!true` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the function is chaining together multiple recursive calls by simply appending a negation operator `!` on each consecutive call and then using that to determine if the number is even or odd based on the end result :

```
even(2) => !!(true)   => (true)(true)       => true
even(3) => !!!(true)  => (true)(!true)      => (true)(false) => false
even(4) => !!!!(true) => (true)(true)(true) => true
```

As you can see, it'll continue to alternate between even and odd calls beginning at zero, and thus let you know if a result is even or odd.

It definitely isn't the prettiest way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation mark is a negation in JavaScript; what the algorithm is doing on that line is saying that whatever value x you have given to even, it's the opposite of x-1